# Sequence where every subset exists as some contiguous subsequence

Tags: algorithms, sets, substrings, subsequences

Given a set (i.e., a collection of distinct elements), how would you find a minimal sequence where every subset of that set can be found as the elements in some contiguous subsequences? The order of elements in a contiguous subsequence does not matter when they are considered as a set.

For example, such a minimal sequence for set $\{1,2,3\}$ is the sequence $[1,2,3,1]$. Here is the explanation.

- The set $\{1,2,3\}$ has 7 non-empty subsets: $$\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,2,3\}.$$
- The sequence $[1,2,3,1]$ contains the following 7 contiguous subsequences
  $$[1], [2], [3], [1,2], [2,3], [3,1], [1,2,3],$$ which correspond to the subsets respectively.
- On the other hand, a sequence of 3 numbers contains only 6 (non-empty) contiguous subsequences.

Comment: Figure out the first few values and look if it appears in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org).

Comment: Wait, *substring* or *subsequence*? That's a big difference. Either way, as an upper bound we have the [de Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence), which are the shortest strings containing all substrings of length $n$ over some alphabet. Probably you can get shorter if you don't care about order like you do.

Comment: Following the hint of @orlp, I googled "unordered De Bruijn" and our friends at math.SE had some first thoughts: [de Bruijn sequence in which order of subsquences doesn't matter](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1616823/45179). Note that in a de Bruijn sequence there are supposed to be no repetitions, so that will be a stronger requirement than "shortest".

Comment: Just adding here, an obvious lower bound for the length of such a string is $\frac{2^n}{n}$, as a set contains $2^n$ subsets but a string om some $m$ characters only contains about $nm$ substrings of length at most $n$. Achieving this lower bound implies that every subset is represented only once and no substring is a multiset, which still sounds pretty optimistic.

Comment: @Highheath I think this can be improved to the central binomial coefficient (plus around $n/2$), which also seems optimistic.

Comment: Can you give a formal definition of what your string should satisfy? Try to be as precise as possible.

Comment: @orlp What is the difference is between a string and a sequence. I am not sure which I intended to use.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I tried to add a little more description to the question, but if it is not sufficient, please let me know what is still ambiguous.

Comment: You should explain that by subsequence, you mean a *contiguous* subsequence. Also, for a subsequence to match a set, it is allowed that symbols repeat in it. For example, 12231 is also a solution (albeit not a minimum length one). Is that on purpose?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you. I've modified the question to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: @magnetlion Here is the last ambiguity. when a subset of that set is found as the elements in some contiguous subsequence, should the elements in that contiguous subsequence be distinct? For example, can subset $\{1,2,3\}$ of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ correspond to the subsequence $[1,2,2,3]$ of the sequence $[1,2,2,3,1,3,4,1,2,4,2,3,4]$?